# Show option chosen by ajax from a select

Tags: php, ajax

Hello I am trying to choose an option from the select to show me the option chosen on the page by ajax but the code is not working if you can help me thanks

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0 /jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function fetch_select(val){
            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: 'ajax.php',
                datatype:'json',
                data: {option:val},
                success: function (response) {
                    $('#print-ajax').html(response);//This will print you result
                }
            });
        }
    </script>

  <div id="select_box">
        <select onchange="fetch_select(this.value);">
            <option value="10">state</option>
            <option value="20">20</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <p id="print-ajax"></p><!--Result will print here-->
```

ajax.php

```
echo $_POST['option'];
```

Comment: You have given `datatype:'json'` in ajax but returning simple string ?Also check what does  `response` has in it

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes jQuery file not working while you put it at the top of Body tag. 
 Currently your code is perfect. But my suggest is try this.

```
  <div id="select_box">
    <select onchange="fetch_select(this.value);">
        <option value="10">state</option>
        <option value="20">20</option>
    </select>
   </div>
<p id="print-ajax"></p><!--Result will print here-->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0 /jquery.min.js"> 
 </script>
 <script>
    function fetch_select(val){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'ajax.php',
            dataType:'JSON',
            data: {option:val},
            success: function (response) {
                $('#print-ajax').html(response);//This will print you result
            }
        });
    }
 </script>
```

Sometimes "post" small format creates issues. So always use "POST" as a capital format.
Hope it will be work for you.